# Not able to connect to redis server from docker container

Tags: docker, redis, jedis

My docker version is 1.13.1.
I am trying to connect to redis-server from my docker container,but I am getting  connection refused error.Detailed logs are given below:

> Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>           at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:207) [jedis-2.9.0.jar:]
>           at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:93)
>   [jedis-2.9.0.jar:]
>           at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1767)
>   [jedis-2.9.0.jar:]
>           at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:106)
>   [jedis-2.9.0.jar:]
>           at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:888)
>   [commons-pool2-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
>           at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:432)
>   [commons-pool2-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
>           at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:361)
>   [commons-pool2-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
>           at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:49) [jedis-2.9.0.jar:]
>           ... 27 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
>           at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
>           at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:184) [jedis-2.9.0.jar:]
>           ... 34 more

when i give `--net="host"` option this error is gone,but when i give

```
--add-host=parent-host:`ip route show | grep docker0 | awk '{print \$9}'`
```

I get the error,although the container is able to connect to Db on a different VM,but not connecting to redis-server present on self hosting machine.

Comment: Couple of questions: Is redis running in docker? What OS are you using?

Comment: OS is rhel 7.Redis is installed on the same host machine outside the docker.Redis & Docker is installed on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that you are trying to connect to redis via `localhost` rather than `parent-host`. Make sure that you are connecting to redis via `parent-host` when creating the Jedis connection.

The reason `--net=host` option works, is that in this case `localhost` will refer to the IP of the host machine and not to that of the container.

Also, make sure that there is an enty for `parent-host` in `/etc/hosts` inside the container.

Comment: --add-host configures that in /etc/hosts.I have tried with ip/localhost/parent-host,but not connecting.